# ios : questions about NavigationController. Mandatory or not ?

Tags: ios

i have a question about NavigationController.

First, is a Navigation Controller mandatory if i use the Storyboard and several views ?

I have a first ViewController and i have made a link (Storyboard Segue) in Push mode to another view (inappsettingskit view). Is it mandatory to have a NavigationController for this to work or can i open the second view via Push without the help of a NavigationController ?

Another question : i have tried to add a NavigationController linked (root) to my main ViewController. But i don't want to have a navigation bar on this view. It automatically puts a Navigation Bar with "SHOW" button on this view. Can i remove it ?

I have tried to remove it in the options of the NavigationController (uncheck Navigation bar) but it still appears behing my status bar ! how can i totally remove it ?

[image]

Last question : if i link a button in the view for the Push Segue to the second viewcontroller, it works. But if i link the button from a toolbar, it doesn't work.. What is missing ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using push segues, yes, you should have a navigation controller. If you don't want the navigation bar to be visible, select the navigation controller in Interface Builder and uncheck the "Shows Navigation Bar" option in the attributes inspector in the rightmost panel in Interface Builder.

[image]

You can show or hide the navigation bar for your controller programmatically via [`setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW9).

By having a navigation controller whose navigation bar is hidden, you enjoy the features of the navigation controller's ability to keep track of a stack of view controllers, giving you the ability to pop view controllers (or pop "to" a particular controller or pop to the root controller). You obviously lose the built in "back" button, though, if the navigation bar is hidden.

Finally, if you want buttons in a `UIToolbar` or a navigation bar, you should use a `UIBarButtonItem` (listed as a "Bar Button Item" in the Interface Builder list of controls).

Comment: sorry the problem of my SHOW was bad code not commented .. everything works fine now

Answer (score 1):

1.) No, a nav controller just makes navigating between multiple views much easier.

2.) in order for the standard "Push" segue to work, you must use a navigation controller

3.) You can hide the navigation bar in code.  A good place to do this is in `viewWillAppear`

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

I'm not sure why your button on the toolbar doesn't work, but try using a `UIBarButtonItem` instead of a `UIButton`

Comment: ok the UIBarButtonItem works great .. instead of a UIButton inside a UIBarButton, thanks